# How to populate forms with multidimensional names

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array, laravel-4

I'm using larave4 and cannot populate forms with multidimensional names.
I need to pre-populate form with data to display to the screen.

I understand and have tested the following works

```
$values = array( );
$values['username'] = 'Ned Stark';
$values['email'] = 'my@email.com';

$fake = new FakeModle( ) //empty model for filling
$fake->fill($values);

Form::make($fake);
```

So long as the input field names match the names of the values used to fill the model all works fine. The form is populated with the values.

However if I have multidimensional names for my form inputs it does not work.
I have tried many variations such as.

```
$values = array( );
$values['account_details']['username'] = 'Ned Stark';
$values['account_details[username]'] = 'Ned Stark';
$values['account_details-username'] = 'Ned Start';
```

To work with inputs that will look like

```
<input type="text" name="account_details[username]" />
```

from

```
$fake = new FakeModle( ) //empty model for filling
$fake->fill($values);

Form::make($fake);
Form::Input('text','account_details[username]',null);
```

Cannot get it to work or find any detials on this.
How do I get the form values populated with multidimensional input names?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really get your problem. Are you trying to fill the Model with the multidemsiol array or the form? And why do you have to use this multidimensional array?

Comment: You need to post more information. What you are asking doesnt make any sense. Why do you want multidimensional names in your forms?

Comment: I am using multidimensional arrays in the form. This is what I need to do. I want to pre-popluate them with data when displaying the form to the user. Is it possible with laravel?